# Is there a way to mock module per every story

Tags: storybook

I am using storybook with nextjs project and want to mock entire modules like for example (useMemo)
i used this addon https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-module-mock
but it have run time error with styled-components in my project

i used jest.mock before storybook something like that

```
import randomColor from "randomcolor";


jest.mock("randomColor", () => {
  return {
    randomColor: () => {
      return mockColor('#123456');
    }
  }
});
```

but i can't experience that here with storybook